# Filter using @property field django

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to filter based on @property field to generate a queryset. My model as below.

```
class PED(models.Manager):
    def ped(self):
        ped = self.provision_start_date + relativedelta(months = self.po_duration )
        return ped

`class PrHW(models.Model):
    po_duration = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    provision_start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def provision_end_date(self):
        provision_end_date = self.provision_start_date + relativedelta(months=self.po_duration)
        return provision_end_date`

    objects = models.Manager()
    ped = PED()
```

Since "provision_end_date" is a calculated field, it is not part of PrHW.objects.all() and hence I am unable create queryset using it as a filter option (eg, generate list of PrHW objects where provision_end_date is less than today - This generates error that "provision_end_date" is not a valid field; which was expected). I tried creating custom model manager but still I am unable to access either the @property field or other fields such as "provision_start_date" in the custom manager. May be this would be straight forward but even after several searches, unable to get the hang of it. Any help is appreciated.

I have included the models manager code as well where I have tried to move the calculation of provision_end_date functionality. When I run PrHW.ped.ped(), it throws me the error: "AttributeError: 'PED' object has no attribute 'provision_start_date'" where provision_start_date is db field.

Answer (score -1):

The @property decorator allows you to access the model field as if it was a regular property.

This means you can call *provision_start_date*  as if it were a variable:

> start_date = prwh.provision_start_date

Also, you can do the checks like this

> if prwh.provision_start_date < today:
> "return something"

Comment: OP's question is that this can't be used in Django queryset filter, e.g. `PrHW.objects.all().filter(provision_start_date__lt=today)`.